# Go - Example about crypto/rand

Tags: random, cryptography, go

Could put a little example about the use of `crypto/rand` [1]?

The function `Read` has as parameter an array of bytes. Why? If it access to */dev/urandom* to get the random data.

```
func Read(b []byte) (n int, err os.Error)
```

[1] http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
func Read(b []byte) (n int, err os.Error)
```

`Read` is a helper function that calls `Reader.Read`. `Reader` is defined as: `var Reader io.Reader`.

[crypto/rand/](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/)

`io.Reader` is the interface that wraps the basic `Read` method.

`Read` reads up to `len(p)` bytes into `p`. It returns the number of bytes read (`0 <= n <= len(p)`) and any error encountered. Even if `Read` returns `n < len(p)`, it may use all of `p` as scratch space during the call. If some data is available but not `len(p)` bytes, `Read` conventionally returns what is available rather than block waiting for more.

At the end of the input stream, `Read` returns `0, os.EOF`. `Read` may return a non-zero number of bytes with a non-`nil` err. In particular, a `Read` that exhausts the input may return n > `0, os.EOF`.

```
type Reader interface {
    Read(p []byte) (n int, err os.Error)
}
```

[io/#Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader)

For example, to read the first 16 random bytes,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "crypto/rand"
)

func main() {
    b := make([]byte, 16)
    n, err := rand.Read(b)
    fmt.Println(n, err, b)
}
```

Using a package `init()` function, `crypto/rand` defaults to using `/dev/urandom`.

```
// Easy implementation: read from /dev/urandom.
// This is sufficient on Linux, OS X, and FreeBSD.
func init() { Reader = &devReader{name: "/dev/urandom"} }
```

[crypto/rand/rand.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/rand/rand.go#L22)

Comment: You can access to */dev/urandom* because it has been defined on `init()`, but not to `newReader` (which uses */dev/random*) because it's unexported.

Comment: Because newReader and devReader are not exported, effectively, /dev/urandom is always used.